# Issue whenever round images intersect with CGRect in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, uiimageview, cgrect, intersect

In my application I have it so that whenever two round images intersect with each other the game ends, but the problem that I am seeing is that the two images are actually intersecting before they actually touch one another. I have tried multiple examples to try to solve my problem, but none of them seem to work. Here is the code I have implemented as of now...

```
creature.layer.backgroundColor=[[UIColor clearColor] CGColor];
creature.layer.cornerRadius=25;
creature.layer.masksToBounds = YES;

ball1.layer.backgroundColor=[[UIColor clearColor] CGColor];
ball1.layer.cornerRadius=20;
ball1.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
```

Is there anything that I can do so that that instead of the frames of the images colliding it is the center of the images that collide?

Comment: Do you really want to know when the centers collide, or when the outside of the circles do?

Comment: Either would be fine because in the end for what I am creating it would not matter what I base the collision off of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, UIKit does not contain the right tools for collision detection (or game development). Why don't you try SpriteKit? Now, to try and answer your question, the best way I can think of using UIKit would be to approximate your rounded corners using `CGRect` (3 of them per corner should do the trick). You could also do this approximation using 3 or more arbitrary points on one rounded corner's path and check if either of them is inside the other's object path (this implies that you'd use `CGPaths` to describe the rounded corners rectangle not the layer's corner radius.